# How to ignore key press on keyboard when some method is called?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm making JavaFX application.

I assigned key pressess on keybord at the beginning in Initizlize method.When I press key "1" some random card with text appear in main window. I can fold this card and see another text by pressing "R" on keyboard. I can also remove this card to right  by "BACKSPACE" and remove to left by "ESCAPE"

The problem is: if I don't press digit keys like "1" to show my card in main window. The key codes "BACKSPACE" and "ESCAPE" still work and if I press it a card is removed(some animation) even there is no card in main window

SO, I've decided to disable key presses "ESCAPE" and "BACKSPACE"  if there is no card in main window, and then to enable it when a card appears in main window.

In other words to enable "ESCAPE" and "BACKSPACE" only after some method that shows a card in main window

**How can I do that?**

Controller:

```
@FXML  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

//key commands
mainAnchor.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
  switch (event.getCode()) {


    case DIGIT1:          
      showRandomQuestionCat1();
      showRandomCard();

      break;

    case DIGIT2:          
      showRandomQuestionCat2();
      showRandomCard();
      break;    

    case R:
      flipCardBack();
      break;


    case ESCAPE:
      hideRandomCard();
      break;

    case BACK_SPACE:
      removeCard();
      flipCardBackSpace();
      break;
     }
   });

 }
```

This is how a card is shown:

```
//show random card in main window
private void showRandomCard(){

if (!animationRunning) {
  animationRunning = true;

  TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition();
  tt.setDuration(Duration.millis(300));
  tt.setNode(randomCard);
  tt.setFromY(950);
  tt.setFromX(-600);
  tt.setToY(0);
  tt.setToX(0);

  TranslateTransition ttRandomBack = new TranslateTransition();
  ttRandomBack.setDuration(Duration.millis(300));
  ttRandomBack.setNode(randomCardBack);
  ttRandomBack.setFromY(950);
  ttRandomBack.setFromX(-600);
  ttRandomBack.setToY(0);
  ttRandomBack.setToX(0);

  RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(300), randomCard);
  rt.setByAngle(360);
  rt.setRate(1);
  rt.setCycleCount(1);
  rt.setOnFinished(evt -> animationRunning = false);

  RotateTransition rtBack = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(300), randomCardBack);
  rtBack.setByAngle(360);
  rtBack.setRate(1);
  rtBack.setCycleCount(1);
  rtBack.setOnFinished(evt -> animationRunning = false);

  tt.play();
  ttRandomBack.play();
  rt.play();
  rtBack.play();
   }
 }
```

This is how a card with text is removed:

```
private void removeCard() {

if (!animationRunning) {
  animationRunning = true;

  TranslateTransition tt2 = new TranslateTransition();
  tt2.setDuration(Duration.millis(300));
  tt2.setNode(outOfCards);
  tt2.setFromY(0);
  tt2.setFromX(0);
  tt2.setToY(-950);
  tt2.setToX(600);

  TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition();
  tt.setDuration(Duration.millis(300));
  tt.setNode(randomCard);
  tt.setFromY(0);
  tt.setFromX(0);
  tt.setToY(-950);
  tt.setToX(600);



  TranslateTransition ttRandomBack = new TranslateTransition();
  ttRandomBack.setDuration(Duration.millis(300));
  ttRandomBack.setNode(randomCardBack);
  ttRandomBack.setFromY(0);
  ttRandomBack.setFromX(0);
  ttRandomBack.setToY(-950);
  ttRandomBack.setToX(600);

  RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(300), randomCard);
  rt.setByAngle(360);
  rt.setRate(1);
  rt.setCycleCount(1);
  rt.setOnFinished(evt -> animationRunning = false);

  RotateTransition rt2 = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(300), outOfCards);
  rt2.setByAngle(360);
  rt2.setRate(1);
  rt2.setCycleCount(1);
  rt2.setOnFinished(evt -> animationRunning = false);

  RotateTransition rtBack = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(300), randomCardBack);
  rtBack.setByAngle(360);
  rtBack.setRate(1);
  rtBack.setCycleCount(1);
  rtBack.setOnFinished(evt -> animationRunning = false);

  tt2.play();
  rt2.play();
  tt.play();
  ttRandomBack.play();

  rt.play();
  rtBack.play();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could have `hideRandomCard()` and `removeCard()` return when a card is visible in your `main window` to ignore functionality (for multiple methods, `return false` to break that case early)

Comment: Otherwise, have a flag in your Controller that is reflects when a card is visible

Comment: @DarceVader I need to use keys(BACKSPACE and ESCAPE) for removing a  card when a card is in main window and don't use keys(BACKSPACE and ESCAPE) when  there is no  any card in main window.

Comment: @DarceVader What is flags? How can I use it in my code? Is there some method that prevent key presses in Java?

Comment: I don't know of any particular flags for each key in the way that you're describing. Do you have a way of knowing when cards are present in your main menu? In your provided code, when you press either `Backspace` or `Escape`, you call some methods. From my understanding, you want to skip these methods when cards are not present, correct?

Comment: @DarceVader Yes! you are right, I just wanna disable that methods that can make removing a card when there is no card in main window, otherwise to disable keys (BACKSPACE or ESCPAE) that call that methods